# FireBug's Net tab not showing http response?

Tags: firebug, httpwebresponse

I'm using [this simple node.js code example](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/examples/login/app.js) but I don't understand why FireBug doesn't show the html response in it's net tab.

I've cleared and disabled the FireFox cache.  I start the server and navigate straight to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/login`.  When viewed in FireBug's Net tab, the response is as expected (i.e. it has html code).

Entering the login details and clicking the submit shows a `POST /login` to `127.0.0.1:3000` with parameters `username=bob&password=secret` which is good (though it also has the same response for the login page?... a bit odd, don't really understand that).  This post request shows as having '302 Moved Temporarily' which is expected as [the node.js code dealing with the POST request to '/login'](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/examples/login/app.js#L114) gives a redirect to '/'. However the `GET 127.0.0.1:3000` request shown in FireBug then doesn't have any response or HTML component.  So why does this content not show in FireBug's Net tab?  If you then hit refresh you'll see the response part of the GET request populated with the expected html.

Odd.  Bug in FireBug or am I missing something?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah this is just a FireBug bug.  Checked in Chrome and all responses are there as expected.

Comment: Was a solution to this ever found? Its 2 years later and this still seems to happen in firebug.

Comment: @Shayne no and I didn't file a bug report, I just used Chrome's developer tools instead.  If you file a report with FireBug please post it back here as an answer and I'll mark it correct.